# Linux, adb and Google Pixel 3a - No connection

Tags: android, adb, linux-mint, cinnamon, google-pixel

I am trying to install **GrapheneOS** on a brand new **Google Pixel 3a**, but I cannot connect to it using **adb**, so I cannot install **GrapheneOS**. Does anyone have any suggestions on what else to try?

**Hardware info**:

Google Pixel 3a with fully upgraded Android 10 (security update : August 5 2020)

**Version info**:

ADB:
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 30.0.0-2

Fastboot:
fastboot version 30.0.0-2

**Things I have tried that DID NOT work (in no particular order)**:

- Activated developer mode
- Activated USB debugging
- Activated Stay awake (suggested on some forum)
- Activated OEM Unlocking (suggested on some forum)
- Activated View attribute inspection (suggested on some forum)
- Tried Revoke USB debugging authorizations (suggested on some forum)
- Tried all five available USB configurations

  - File transfer/Android studio
  - USB tethering
  - MIDI
  - PTP
  - No data transfer
- Tried 3 different USB cables (one brand new)
- Tried using 3 different linux devices (2 * **Linux Mint** and 1 * **Manjaro Cinnamon**)
- Tried reinstall of **android-tools** (via pacman), as well as completely removing it and installing it again
- Tried installing **android-udev**
- Tried opening port 5037 (sudo ufw allow 5307)
- Tried disabling **UFW** completely (sudo ufw disable)
- Tried **lsusb** (no new device detected detected)
- Added my self to group **adbusers**
- Rebooted both the **Pixel 3a** and my machines several times
- Obviously unplugging and plugging in the device all the time

My main machine (Manjaro Cinnamon) could connect to my old phone (Samsung Galaxy Note 8) just a few weeks ago without problem.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved.

I was using various USB-A to USB-A cables, and two different USB-A to USB-C adapters, combinations that did not work. I went out and bought a 0.5 meter USB-A to USB-C cable (that support both data and charging) and it worked immediately.

I can only assume that it was the adapters that messed things up.